# Memory Usage and Garbage Collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, local-variables

I have read many things about memory usage in java.

My questions points towards game making.
Every frame I will call methods up to 500 times as I am creating a binary tree.
Each node will call a function and will create 10 local variables.

1. Is it better for the memory usage and or for the garbage collector to create a separate class which holds all the needed variables, instantiate it once and give every node a reference to this object ?

If my first question is actually better, is it more "expensive" to call .getSomething() from a separate object than storing the thing you want to get in the own object ?

Thank you all!

Comment: *Local* variables are stored on the call stack, and are released as soon as method returns. Therefore they are not eligible for GC. That of course says nothing about any objects *referenced* by the local variables, but how they are affected by GC depends entirely on how many different references there are to the objects, so impossible to say without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As a rule of thumb, the less objects you create, the less pressure you will have on the GC. So if every "node" in your application needs to access the same set of values, putting these values in one single object is certainly better than allocate them for each node over and over again.
2. Most likely not. The JIT compiler will most likely inline these calls if they are executed often.

As mentioned in the comment of your question, local *primitive* variables will be allocated on the stack and are not subject to garbage collection. In some cases, even objects can be allocated on the stack due to the JIT compiler's escape analysis technique.

Generally speaking, if you really want to find out how your application behaves in terms of GC and allocations, you should profile it (e.g. with Java Flight Recorder's Allocation Profile) and take a look at the GC log.
Furthermore, you should tune your application based these results rather than prematurely.